How to add collision detection in my Python turtle maze game
In my Python maze game, I need to add collision detection for my walls so the player doesn't just go over the walls. I've tried many ways but none have seemed to work.
I think using the arrays to detect the collision is possible, but I don't know how to do that exactly as I'm kind of new to Python and turtle specifically.
import turtle
import random
import time

print("TURTLE MAZE")


player = turtle.Turtle()
player.penup()
player.speed(0)
player.shape("square")
player.pensize(5)
player.color('red')
player.pencolor('white')
player.goto(-210,-210)

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.title("Maze ")
screen.bgcolor("White")
screen.setup(width=1000, height=600)


grid = [
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ,2, 2 ,2, 2 ,2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, ],
    [2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ,0, 0 ,0, 0 ,0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 8, 0, 0 ,1, 1 ,0, 1 ,0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 ,1, 0 ,0, 1 ,0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ,1, 0 ,1, 1 ,0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 8, 0, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1, 0 ,0, 1 ,0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0 ,1, 1 ,0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 ,1, 1 ,1, 0 ,0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, ],
    [2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 ,1, 0 ,1, 1 ,1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 8, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,1, 0 ,0, 1 ,0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 ,0, 0 ,0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 ,1, 1 ,0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, ],
    [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 ,1, 0 ,0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 ,1, 1 ,1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 ,0, 0 ,0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 ,1, 1 ,0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 ,0, 1 ,0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 8 ,0, 0 ,0, 1, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 2, ],
    [2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 ,1, 1 ,1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0 ,0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 ,1, 1 ,0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,0, 0 ,0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, ],
    [2, 4, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ,0, 1 ,0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 2, ],
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ,2, 2 ,2, 2 ,2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,  ]
    ]

tiles = ['empty', 'wall']

pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.penup()
pen.speed(0)
pen.shape("square")
pen.setundobuffer(None)

def draw_grid(pen, grid):
    pen.clear()
    top = 230
    left = -230
    
    colors = ["black", "lightblue", "blue", "orange", "yellow", "green", "purple", "red","sky blue"]
    
    for y in range(len(grid)):
        for x in range(len(grid[0])):
            screen_x = left + (x * 20)
            screen_y = top - (y * 20)
            color_number = grid[y][x]
            color = colors[color_number]
            pen.color(color)
            pen.goto(screen_x, screen_y)
            pen.stamp()

draw_grid(pen, grid)

class Movement:
    def movePlayerRight():
        x = player.xcor()
        x += 20
        player.setx(x)
        print(x)

    def movePlayerLeft():
        x = player.xcor()
        x -= 20
        player.setx(x)
        print(x)
    def movePlayerUp():
        y = player.ycor()
        y += 20
        player.sety(y)
        print(y)

    def movePlayerDown():
        y = player.ycor()
        y -= 20
        player.sety(y)
        print(y)


    screen.listen()
    screen.onkeypress(movePlayerRight, "Right")
    screen.onkeypress(movePlayerLeft, "Left")
    screen.onkeypress(movePlayerUp, "Up")
    screen.onkeypress(movePlayerDown, "Down")

Movement()

while True:
    screen.update()
    if player.xcor() < -210:
        player.setx(player.xcor() + 20)
        print("Nuh uh, Dont try go outside...")
    if player.xcor() > 210:
        player.setx(player.xcor() - 20)
        print("Nuh uh, Dont try go outside...")
    if player.ycor() < -210:
        player.sety(player.ycor() + 20)
        print("Nuh uh, Dont try go outside...")
    if player.ycor() > 210:
        player.sety(player.ycor() - 20)
        print("Nuh uh, don't try go outside...")
going = True
while going == True:
  screen.update()


Avoid while True:--it just slams the CPU as hard as the system can run, so it'll be super fast on fast computers and slow on slower computers. ontimer provides a consistent framerate. As for your main question, the grid approach can work, but I don't see that you're attempting to reconcile the turtle's coordinates with a grid coordinate to check if it's a 1 or a 0. Try doing that. Take the turtle's coordinates and floor divide by the grid size to hone in on a cell.

Hm, That was an idea, how would that work

while True is OK, just use time.sleep(0.05) (or another more appropriate number) in your loop so things become slow enough to see. @ggorlen is right that this doesn't provide constant framerate and a 'proper' game would do it differently but this program is for learning purposes.

@julaine Sleeping is a step better, but it also blocks the thread from receiving input and processing other things, so it can lead to other issues down the line.

You can use this function:
def isCollided(col, self, radius):
    return abs(col.xcor() - self.xcor()) < radius and abs(col.ycor() - self.ycor()) < radius

This will return True if "col" is within "radius" of "self"
Note that the collision box is not a circle, the 'radius' parameter prefers to half of the width of the collision box. e.g. if radius is 10, then it detects for a 20x20 square around the turtle.
Example use:
#Python

from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import keyboard

#setup

screen = Screen()

screen.screensize(250, 250)
screen.title("collision test")

t1 = Turtle("turtle")
t2 = Turtle("turtle")

t1.goto(-100, -100)
t2.goto(100, 100)


def isCollided(col, self, radius): #isCollided function
    return abs(col.xcor() - self.xcor()) < radius and abs(col.ycor() - self.ycor()) < radius 

#Main Loop

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("right"): #move right it right arrow is pressed
        t1.goto(t1.xcor()+2, t1.ycor())
    if keyboard.is_pressed("up"): #etc
        t1.goto(t1.xcor(), t1.ycor()+2)
    if keyboard.is_pressed("left"): 
        t1.goto(t1.xcor()-2, t1.ycor())
    if keyboard.is_pressed("down"):
        t1.goto(t1.xcor(), t1.ycor()-2)
    

    if isCollided(t2, t1, 10): #check if t1 is within 10 pixels of t2
        print("It works!")     #If so, print "it works"

#INSTRUCTIONS:
#Press the arrow keys to move one turtle
#If you are within 10 pixels of the other turtle, the console will print "It works!"
#You can use this as a simple collision test


The name "radius" seems to imply you have a circle as a collision box, but the actual shape your formula describes is a square of side-length 2*"radius". Not bad though.

@julaine Thanks, now that I think about it I can't really see how it would be good for a maze game though...

I think the formula is fine for a maze game but I just wanted to give a heads up because people read 'radius' and think 'circle'.

@julaine ok then I added a clarification so people don't get confused

This approach doesn't appropriate for this maze game which has a backing grid that indicates what is, or isn't, a barrier.  I.e. there are no two turtle collisions as isCollided() assumes.  Also, can you clarify why one would want this specific implementation when turtle has a similar built-in distance() method that can be used for collisions between two turtles and collisions with turtles and coordinates.

@cdlane Yeah, j realised it probably wouldn’t be good for a maze game right after I posted it :/ I guess distance() would probably work fine in most cases but if you want a collision square (or rectangle) then you could use isCollided()

The key here is inverting these two equations:
screen_x = left + (x * 20)
screen_y = top - (y * 20)

which compute screen coordinates from grid coordinates.  For collision testing, you want to compute grid coordinates from screen coordinates per @ggorlen:
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

GRID = [
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, ],
    [2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 8, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 8, 0, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, ],
    [2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 8, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, ],
    [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 2, ],
    [2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, ],
    [2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, ],
    [2, 4, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 2, ],
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, ],
]

COLORS = ['black', 'lightblue', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'purple', 'red', 'sky blue']

TOP_EDGE = 230
LEFT_EDGE = -230
GRID_UNIT = 20

class Movement:
    def __init__(self, grid):
        self.grid = grid

        screen.onkeypress(self.movePlayerRight, 'Right')
        screen.onkeypress(self.movePlayerLeft, 'Left')
        screen.onkeypress(self.movePlayerUp, 'Up')
        screen.onkeypress(self.movePlayerDown, 'Down')

        screen.listen()

    def movePlayerRight(self):
        player.setx(player.xcor() + GRID_UNIT)
        self.check_move()

    def movePlayerLeft(self):
        player.setx(player.xcor() - GRID_UNIT)
        self.check_move()

    def movePlayerUp(self):
        player.sety(player.ycor() + GRID_UNIT)
        self.check_move()

    def movePlayerDown(self):
        player.sety(player.ycor() - GRID_UNIT)
        self.check_move()

    def check_move(self):
        x = (player.xcor() - LEFT_EDGE) // GRID_UNIT
        y = (TOP_EDGE - player.ycor()) // GRID_UNIT

        color_number = self.grid[y][x]

        if color_number in (1, 2):
            player.undo()  # tried to cross a barrier

        screen.update()

def draw_grid(pen, grid):
    pen.clear()

    for y in range(len(grid)):
        for x in range(len(grid[0])):
            color_number = grid[y][x]
            color = COLORS[color_number]
            pen.color(color)

            screen_x = x * GRID_UNIT + LEFT_EDGE
            screen_y = TOP_EDGE - y * GRID_UNIT
            pen.goto(screen_x, screen_y)
            pen.stamp()

    screen.update()

screen = Screen()
screen.title("Maze")
screen.setup(width=1000, height=600)
screen.tracer(False)

pen = Turtle()
pen.shape('square')
pen.penup()

draw_grid(pen, GRID)

player = Turtle()
player.shape('square')
player.penup()
player.color('white', 'red')
player.goto(LEFT_EDGE + GRID_UNIT, GRID_UNIT - TOP_EDGE)

Movement(GRID)

screen.update()
screen.mainloop()

